# Differences between attributes in Request, Session and ServletContext

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I am having trouble understanding the differences between these 3 ways of setting attributes:

```
// String as attribute of request
req.setAttribute("name", "Sluggo");

// Integer as attribute of session
req.getSession().setAttribute("age", 10);

// Date as attribute of context
getServletContext().setAttribute("today", new Date());
```

1. What are the differences?
2. When should you use each?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Comment: @AustinT: For Servlet 2.5, would the ServletContext.getInitParameter() return the same attribute set by ServletContext.setAttribute() ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those three have different scopes:

- request attributes live for the life of that request/response cycle
- session attributes for the life of that session
- `ServletContext` is across the servlet context and it lives until context gets destroyed.

Comment: The answer is too circular to be helpful. The link provided above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi) provides a much more detailed response.

Comment: @user823447 I agree. Saying that the session attributes last for the life of teh session and that the `ServletContext` is across the servlet context explains nothing.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: For Servlet 2.5, would the ServletContext.getInitParameter() return the same attribute set by ServletContext.setAttribute() ?

Answer (score 27):

> A **ServletContext** attribute is an object bound into a context
>   through the `ServletContext.setAttribute()` method and which is
>   available to ALL Servlets (thus JSP) in that context, or to other
>   contexts via the `getContext()` method. By definition a context
>   attribute exists locally in the VM where they were defined. So,
>   they're unavailable on distributed applications.
>
> **Session** attributes are bound to a Session, as a mean to provide state to a set of related HTTP requests. Session attributes are
>   available ONLY to those Servlets which join the session. They're also
>   unavailable to different JVMs in distributed scenarios. Objects can be
>   notified when they're bound/unbound to the Session implementing the
>   `HttpSessionBindingListener` interface.
>
> **Request** attributes are bound to a specific request object, and they last as far as the request is resolved or while it keeps being
>   dispatched from Servlet to Servlet. They're used more as communication
>   channel between Servlets via the `RequestDispatcher` Interface (since
>   you can't add Parameters...) and by the container. Request attributes
>   are very useful in web apps when you must provide setup information
>   between information providers and the information presentation layer
>   (a JSP) that is bound to a specific request and need not be available
>   any longer, which usually happens with sessions without a rigorous
>   control strategy.
>
> **IN SUMMARY**, we can say that:
>
> - **Context** attributes are meant for infra-structure, such as shared connection pools.
> - **Session** attributes are meant for contextual information, such as user identification.
> - **Request** attributes are meant for specific request info, such as query results.

*Source: [Servlets Interview Questions by Krishna Srinivasan @ javabeat.net](http://javabeat.net/servlets-interview-questions/)*

Comment: For Servlet 2.5, would the ServletContext.getInitParameter() return the same attribute set by ServletContext.setAttribute() ?